# Class to parse/validate URL for a specific route in Play framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

If I have a URL string, say `https://localhost/users/45`, and I have a route in my Play Framework 2.3 project that looks like

`GET /users/:id   UserController.get(id:Long)`

How can I validate/parse that URL and get the ID out of it? I actually know the specific route/Call that I want to check against. What I really want to do is reverse-reverse routing, something like this:

`routes.UserController.get_parse(url) match {
  case (id:Long) => println("Use the data")
  case _ => throw Exception("Bad URL")`

Is there some mechanism for doing this?

Comment: It's a little bit of an unusual case, since in most cases, one only wants to parse the URL for the current request. If there is an answer to be had, it's in the [routes-compiler](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/routes-compiler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request seems odd, until you consider implementing a REST/hypermedia API.

Suppose the routes file is

```
GET /foo/:id/bar Foo.bar(id)
```

Someone POSTs `{"data":"something", "parent": "/foo/5/bar"}` to `/foo/123/bar`.

Play will extract the id parameter (say, for an internal database id) from the request URL `/foo/123/bar`, but could you do the same thing for parsing `/foo/5/bar`?

---

**The short answer**

No, you can't use the routes file for this.

---

**The long answer**

From the routes file, Play generates code for converting

1. string => calling a controller method with arguments
2. controller method identifier + arguments => string

What you want is either

3. string => controller method + arguments
4. controller method identifier + string => arguments

A couple disadvantages:

#3 is not type safe.

#4 is ambiguous. Multiple routing rules can refer to the same method. You could try *all* rules for that controller method, though that is more complicated, and default arguments may be a problem here.

In any case, the routes-compiler doesn't generate suitable code. It's either just not there, or restricted from accessing.

For example, the routes-compiler generates `target/scala-2.x/src_managed/main/routes_routing.scala` with something like

```
private[this] lazy val Foo_bar0_route = Route(
  "GET",
   PathPattern(
     List(
       StaticPart(Routes.prefix),
       StaticPart(Routes.defaultPrefix),
       StaticPart("/foo/"),
       DynamicPart("id", """[^/]""", true),
       StaticPart("/bar")
     )
   )
)
```

which could help, but `private[this]` prevents it.

Answer (score 0):

Play's router will automatically validate the URL (also against the param types), so you don't need to make additional validation in your action. I.e. if you'll call a `/users/some-string` it will throw 404 Not found...

Comment: I'm not validating the URL the user is calling. The user is passing a URL in as part of the data in a POST, and I'm validating and parsing that data.

Comment: Just concept: how about using WS API: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS to determine if given string is valid route (i.e. via HEAD request)?